# jQuery.fn.jquery equivalent for jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

jQuery.fn.jquery equivalent for jQuery Mobile?

To programmatically check the version of jQuery one can simply use "jQuery.fn.jquery".

Might there be a similar method available to return the Mobile plugin's loaded version? I am unable to find it sifting though the Object, but maybe I missed something...

Any format will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.mobile.version
```

That should do it. From the current documentation page here - http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html, it returns:

```
"1.1.0-rc.1"
```

Comment: Works! Had some issues getting a good mobile lib, so I suspect that not all versions of the lib file have the version object. hmmmm